# Example using polymer noflo-ui connecting to a websocket

Tags: node.js, polymer, noflo

I need to connect my polymer component, which uses noflo-ui to a websocket server.

Does anyone know or have any examples.

Answer (score -1):

Could you be more specific? for using websockets in polymer you can go with something like:
https://github.com/elierotenberg/x-websocket